# Fullscreen Modal Window Usability Issues

Tags: popup, fullscreen, modal, overlay

There is a new trend of fullscreen modals used in web applications. Please refer a sample in the below link (Click the green colored "See it in action" button):

https://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-fullscreen.html#demo

**Would like to know the recommended scenarios to use such dialogs?**

For instance, if a user previews some content (say an attachment such as image, video, PDF, etc.), then this would be perfect because of the need of larger real estate. On the other hand, if the user has to refer something (say some data) from the underlying screen so as to complete the task, then this won't be recommended.

Comment: There are potentially thousands of answers to this question - can you narrow it to ask if the interaction is suitable for a specific use?

Comment: There is no specific use. I have asked from a guideline point of view like how Mac OS X has guideline for when to use Document Modal, Application Modal and Modeless dialogs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why is a full screen modal bad for completing tasks?

Comment: There is no "one fits all"-rule about modal window. Read about when to use them here: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/overuse-of-overlays/ and keep in mind that modal windows are harder to use on mobile. The reason to use a FULLSCREEN modal is to avoid distraction of anything but the modal window for the user. I only saw it on navigation concepts... And i'm in a rush so i'm unable yet to write a propper answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that it interrupts the workflow of the user. It is as if your web page was saying "I just want you to focus on this now". This is okay when the action cannot be undone or when it requires special precautions, but it will not feel very friendly if done improperly.

You can use modals for different reasons; here are several:

- A confirmation box, ask yourself whether it would be weird if you did not ask (if the answer is no, then maybe you don't really need it)
- A way to provide focus, if you consider that for a specific task the user should not be distracted by the rest of the web page

One thing is for sure, **you should not use modals only because of space consideration**.

You may want to consider [this best practices for modal windows](http://uxmovement.com/forms/best-practices-for-modal-windows/) as a further reading.